# How to update the "Replacement Value" in ReplaceText Processor using Rest API?

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to know how to update the values in nifi processors using Rest API.
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

For example: I have used below processor structure

```
GetFile>SplitText>ExtractText>ReplaceText>ConvertJSONToSQL>PUTSQL.
```

I have passed following inputs for above processors.,

```
   FileLocation(GetFile).
   validation(ExtractText).
   ReplacementValue(ReplaceText).
   DBCP ConnectionPool,username and pwd for SQL.
```

I just need to use nifi rest api client to write above inputs into processors.

For example : If I give Processor name and input file in Rest API Client then it will write into processor.

Please stop me if anything i'm doing wrong.

Help Appreciated and Tell me any other ways is possible?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you just trying to update the configuration of one processor (ie. configure the properties of the ReplaceText processor)? Also the "input" section, is that a summarized list of things you already done? You say "I have passed the following inputs..." but then "I just need to .. write above inputs into processors". These seem to contradict.

Comment: I need to pass inputs in rest api only not directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mahen,

You can issue a `PUT` request to `/processors/{id}` and provide the new value of the "Replacement Value" property. You'll need to provide JSON body in the request to do this, and you can see the structure by expanding the endpoint noted above on the documentation link you provided, then clicking *ProcessorEntity* > *ProcessorDTO* > *ProcessorConfigDTO* to see the pop-up dialogs with the element listing and examples. You can also quickly get the current values of the processor by issuing a `GET` request to `/processors/{id}`.

Comment: Thanks for your information.
Is there any other way to update processor values without using rest api?

Comment: Well, through the UI, or possibly using an `ExecuteScript` processor.

Comment: How can I pass the values to replacetext processor using execute script?

Comment: `ExecuteScript` provides access to the other components on the graph either via REST access or by using reflection to negotiate the object graph. Neither of those solutions are preferred to direct access via the REST API though. Is there a reason you do not want to use the REST API? That is how the UI performs these actions.